# How do i add social buttons to my github page using the automatic page generator?

Tags: github, github-pages

I'd like to add social buttons (share on twitter, like on Facebook, share on google+) to a github page, which was created using the automatic page generator. Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

as far as i know there's no automated way. but you can do it by editing the html of the github page.

the automatic page generator creates a 'gh-pages' branch with the html, css & js files for the github page you created. you can checkout this branch, edit it as normal and push it back to github.